# Combobox selection problem (Wpf theme BureauBlue)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am using WPF theme BureauBlue, I can only open down items in combobox by clicking the right side arrow on the control. But I should open it clicking any part of combobox. This problem is ruling for all themes. Any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solve the issue :) In theme BureauBlue, in "ComboBoxToggleButton" ControlTemplate, there is a Grid named "grid". I have made IsHitTestVisible property "true" on first rectangle in this grid.

Before I changed;

```
    <Rectangle x:Name="Background" Fill="#FFEAF2FB" Stroke="#FF9EBBDE" 
IsHitTestVisible="false" />
```

After I changed;

```
   <Rectangle x:Name="Background" Fill="#FFEAF2FB" Stroke="#FF9EBBDE" 
IsHitTestVisible="true" />
```